# May you reopen my account?

Tags: support, account-suspension

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020386/dreamchaser

My account is suspended. I like this site very much, and many people are kind and helped me a lot. Sometimes, I also want to help others, but my programming skills are too limited, so I couldn't help others.

Comment: From the suspension notice - "The suspension period ends tomorrow." Can't you wait less than 24 hours?

Comment: The suspension will end tomorrow. When you post new questions (or answers), make sure that they have a decent quality. Also have a look at the [faq#howtoask].

Comment: You realize that you just did the opposite, right? You've drawn attention to your account, which will result in more downvotes/flags and maybe trigger the dreaded/beloved post-ban.

Comment: ChrisF ,i am sorry, i still can't ask a question.

Answer (score 17):

Urr, the idea of your suspension for **low-quality contributions** is to let you realise that the quality of your posts need to be improved.

Judging from the quality of this question however, you still haven't learnt your lesson. Blaming the limitations of your programming skills on your poor quality contributions is not a valid excuse.

**Does your programming ability affect your use of the caps lock or shift key, to enable you to use capital letters?**

Looking at some of your questions, you should also look at the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), to show you how to use lists, format code and the like.

Comment: I'm [William Strunk Jr.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Strunk,_Jr.), and I approve this message.

Comment: You really shouldn't have told him about the caps lock key.

Comment: Note, he updated his question. Basically `s/computer/programming/`.

Comment: @Tim: Does *your* programming not come with a caps lock or shift key? :P

Comment: @Matt _My_ programming comes with a _power glove_.

Comment: i am sorry, i still can't ask a question.

Answer (score 9):

No, the suspension can not be lifted at this time. Your account was suspended because the quality of your writing needs substantial improvement. While we do not expect a drastic improvement within 48 hours, we do hope that the action taken will trigger you to *want* to improve the way you communicate.

Here are some things you can do, beyond the resources you were given when you were contacted:

1. **Read**. Read the other highly up-voted questions on Stack Overflow. What's different about them and the questions you have asked so far?
2. **Write**. Write something every day, perhaps on a blog. Practice getting your point across using the smallest possible combination of words that you can. Take everyday concepts like cooking something and explain them.
3. **Converse**. Find a patient native English speaking friend and practice conversationally using instant messaging.

We don't require perfection, we realize that not everyone is a native English speaker and English is a difficult language to learn. However, we need a *best effort* attempt from you so that our editors can add the final shine to what you write.

Stack Overflow is successful because of the knowledge our community has, and the quality of how that knowledge is conveyed. We must, at all costs, keep that bar as high as possible. Forcing you to become a better communicator is in essence forcing you to become successful, so look at it as an opportunity.

Comment: I always want to make a friends of a native English speaking. but the reality shows me it hard to find it.

Comment: *We must, at all costs keep that bar as high as possible.*  Because, if we do not, all those people who are willing to help others for free will be driven away.

Comment: i am sorry, i still can't ask a question.

Comment: @dreamchaser Unfortunately, it probably means that the system has stopped allowing you to ask questions due to quality issues. The only way to fix that is to get some up votes. Edit some of your questions, perhaps? Provide some good answers .. and you might be able to tip the ban.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Good catch, I've been working, on my comma, problem, lately.

Comment: @TimPost: LOL! ..

Comment: _English is a difficult language to .._ **No, its just completely idiotic, non-sensical and weird....**

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the suspension was to give you the opportunity to consider the content.  It was not personal; we concentrate on the behavior, not the user.

What concerns me most about what you were doing was asking other users to visit other websites to debug and to replicate behaviors for you.  This is not acceptable for a number of reasons.  One among them is the fact that our users consider this a form of spam (artificially driving traffic to other websites for personal profit).  If you attract enough spam flags, your account can be permanently blocked from StackOverflow.  Other measures will prevent you from re-joining.

As Tim said, we don't expect you to be perfect, but we do want you to know that you are doing some things that aren't acceptable here, and we'd appreciate it if you didn't do that.

Comment: oh,my god. you using yaoming's picture as your profile. :(