# What happens when users opens low quality questions?

Tags: support, low-quality-posts

After the automatic question ban the suspension for low quality contribute is still frequent? Which other kind of intervents are issued manually from the moderator in these cases?

And what happens if the users prove a strong effort to improve those low quality questions?

**EDIT**

I've made an extensive search and a selection I'm posting the more useful link I could find

[What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

[How should we respond to persistently low quality question askers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62672/how-should-we-respond-to-persistently-low-quality-question-askers)

[Handling "Problematic" Stack Overflow participants](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20696/handling-problematic-stack-overflow-participants)

[anyone helps me, could you reopen my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114158/anyone-helps-me-could-you-reopen-my-account/114159#114159)

[What happens to user accounts which continuously post bad or spam questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158045/what-happens-to-user-accounts-which-continuously-post-bad-or-spam-questions/158048#158048)

Comment: It would be really useful for me to get a comment on the downvotes.

Comment: you have missed the most important duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th which explains the automated process, and how it kicks in after either bad answers or bad questions reach a certain (nonpublihsed) level. It also covers what may happen after you try to improve bad questions. This question is linked from the main page - I suspect most downvoters feel you should have read it before asking.

Comment: @KateGregory: tjanks, added, however I knowed that automatic mechanism very well (since I experimented it here on meta...)! But I'm adding for the others.

Comment: If you know that mechanism very well, why are you asking this question? Why are you linking to 2+ year old blogs and two-year-old questions from before the mechanism was implemented and asking things that imply you know nothing about the mechanism?

Comment: @KateGregory: becouse I'm interested in the manual suspension only.. now I understand that this wasn't clear and I will edit the question. Have a look on it. Now, I guess it's really more clear, but the lack of comments was misleading me..

Comment: Once a question has answers (and you've accepted one of them) don't vompletely edit it to be a different question. Ask a different question as a different question.

Comment: @KateGregory: yes, I know, but, the question was this from the beginnin. It was not clear to anyone probably.. Comments would help me to understand, but here downvotes seems to be preferred (maybe since they don't imply any effort)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That sentiment applies to both questions and answers.  Consistently poor contributions can lead to both question and answer bans.  Users that are able to demonstrate that they can provide positive contributions can dig themselves out of that hole, potentially, for either case.

Comment: But this can also lead to a suspension? Also for users which proved effort and collaboration?

Comment: @Revious Generally not, as there is no need.  In theory one can be manually suspended for either inappropriate questions or answers though, if you violate the rules in either.

Comment: so a moderator can suspend an user or question ban him?

Comment: @Revious No, a moderator can only suspend someone.  Question bans are automatic.

Comment: thanks. Can you advice me on why I'm getting so many downvotes?

Comment: @Revious Likely for a lack of research; this is all covered in the FAQ and help center.

Comment: thanks, I will verify this and edit my question if I can find some links

Comment: I couldn't find an exact duplicate of my question, however I'm adding to my questions the more interesting answer that I found. If you like my effort, I would appreciate an upvote :-)

Comment: And as for my case: no longer q&a from your account - what to do? So was it automatic - every ban (based solely on downvotes)? And before the ban I was suspended 7 days. Then "no longer". And I'm not a bot but rather a clever person. How to be an autobot-like to dig out likewise?

Comment: @xsi: at the moment I got newly automatic question banned here... Have a look at my "terrible" contribution... I think that from when this site has many contributors he decided to improve quality on the skin of many persons.. this is leading to a lot of polemics and, if there will be an alternative many people could choose to migrate there.. :( I hope someone is considering this aspects

Comment: @Revious There are *lots* of alternatives.  A *huge* number of experts all migrated here due to the expressed purpose that this site has high quality standards.  People love asking crappy questions, but people (or at least, experts) don't like answering crappy questions.  So if you want to ask crappy questions, you're going to end up with crappy answers.  If you want quality answers, you need to ask quality questions.  You don't get to ask crappy questions and get quality answers.

Comment: @Servy: I absolutely don't want crappy answers neither crappy questions. But the world is not b/w, there are shades. Also I personally wonder on which method to use to reach such an objective and which other objective should not be stepped on for reaching the first one.. that's all.. (ps: I voted your comment as useful, we are not in disagreement)